# Does adjustROI change the wholeSize of cv::Mat?

Tags: c++, opencv

UPDATE:

My original question here is not valid, sorry. I left a line out from it, where `m.create` gets called. If there was no answer on this I would delete the question right away.

---

I've just noticed that `Mat::adjustROI` seems to change the `wholeSize` of `cv::Mat`.

```
Mat m(11,11,CV_32FC1);
Size wholeSize, old_size;
Point ofs;
m.locateROI(old_size, ofs);
m.adjustROI(0,old_size.height/2,0,old_size.width/2);
m.locateROI(wholeSize, ofs);
assert(wholeSize==old_size); // fails, wholeSize is now smaller
```

Is this normal?
If so, I suspect reallocation otherwise this could be a source of a memory leak.
If Im right, when does the reallocation occur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran your code, and the assert doesn't fail for me (MSVC 2010). I stepped through it with the debugger and I can also see in the watch window that both sizes are equal (x and y equal to 11). I'm a beginner in OpenCV, but from the documentation of the function it seems to me adjustROI should not modify "wholeSize".

> The method is complimentary to the cv::Mat::locateROI. Indeed, the
>   typical use of these functions is to determine the submatrix position
>   within the parent matrix and then shift the positionsomehow. Typically
>   it can be needed for ﬁltering operations, when pixels outside of the
>   ROI shouldbe taken into account. When all the method’s parameters are
>   positive, it means that the ROI needsto grow in all directions by the
>   speciﬁed amount.